# garage flooding

Tags: garage, flooding

My house is on a steep hill. When it rains the garage floods. I have a concrete floor that is on a slope so need some way to divert the water that floods from the back of the garage down to the front.

Comment: What drainage is already there for the garage?

Comment: The only drainage is at the front of the garage in the form of a drain. The water is coming up from the foundation at the back (uphill) of the garage. The garage door is at the front of the garage.

Answer (score 1):

A French drain would solve your problem. A trench across the area even a foot deep (but deeper is better) with perforated pipe then gravel, some use landscape plastic (full of small holes) to reduce dirt from entering the gravel and pipe. Sod can be put on top of the gravel and it will be the first area to turn brown in the summer. At the end of the pipe run a second pipe down hill until it is close to the surface then cover the end with rock So the water can flow through. There are lots of examples to be found on the internet. Other than trenching it is not a tough job and very effective. Rental of a ditch witch makes it much easier and a nice clean trench just remember to call before you dig to locate buried utilities.

Comment: I can see that this would be the answer if the water were coming into the garage from the outside. However, the problem is that the water is coming up from the foundation inside the garage.

Comment: The water is running down the hill in the earth as it runs into a solid object like your foundation/ stem wall the water pressure is forcing its way in. This is not an unusual case. If the back of your garage is 3' below grade it may take a drain that is 3' deep. My last shop the back corner was 11' below grade alli I did to keep it dry was drop a sock covered perf pipe and back fill with rock or create a very large French drain.